# How to list only subpages title and link in a wordpress page div

Tags: wordpress

I have a webblog using wordpress i'm using wp_list_pages() function to get list its Sub Pages Links (excluding main page) in a list, I've tried the below codes but its returning all Pages Sub Page.

I also tried this Argument **child_of** but its not happning. Please suggest i have tried so many things...

```
<?php

 $output = wp_list_pages('echo=0&depth=1&child_of=0');
    if (is_page( )) {
        $page = $post->ID;
            if ($post->post_parent) {
            $page = $post->post_parent;
            }
        }
        echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will list the subpages and siblings of the current page:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
}
else {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
} ?>
<?php if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )): ?>
<div id="submenu">
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent" ); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Its displaying nothing, i think you did some copy and paste kind of things. I have checked various argument s and method nothing is working. :D

Comment: I think this one is better and compact but there is no result  <?php $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0'); if ($children) { echo $children; } ?>

Comment: Where are you adding the code? Ive tested it and it works for me. Are you sure you have subpages setup on the page your using it on?

Answer (score 0):

```
 U can try this code this code may be useful to u  

<?php
global $wpdb, $post;
$child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *  FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent =    ".$post->ID."   AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT'); ?>
<?php if ( $child_pages ) : 
foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) :
setup_postdata( $pageChild ); ?>
<h2 class="subpagetitle">
<a href="<?php echo  get_permalink($pageChild->ID); ?>" rel="bookmark"
title="<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>">
<?php echo $pageChild->post_title; ?>
</a>
</h2>

<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```